# What would be the value of the limit $\lim _{x\to \infty} (\frac{3x +1}{3x-1})^{4x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

What would be the value of the limit $\lim _{x\to \infty} (\frac{3x +1}{3x-1})^{4x}$?

My initial idea was to divide by x in the numerator and denominator. However that would only solve the inner problem. How can the power be manipulated to evaluate the limit?

Comment: This is a $1^\infty$ indeterminate. Can't you relate it to a well-known case ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\left(\frac{3x +1}{3x-1}\right)^{4x}=\left[\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{3x}\right)^{3x}}{\left(1-\frac{1}{3x}\right)^{3x}}\right]^\frac{4}{3}\to\left[\frac{e}{e^{-1}}\right]^{\frac{4}{3}}=e^\frac{8}{3}$$

Comment: Nice way to keep the symmetry.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks - I often find that prioritising symmetry and clarity in algebra can save work in explaining the steps in words ("sanitising equations", if you will).

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$\dfrac{3x+1}{3x-1}=1+\dfrac2{3x-1}$$

Use $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)^n=e$$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{3x +1}{3x-1}\right)^{4x}=\left[\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac2{3x-1}\right)^{\dfrac{3x-1}2}\right]^{\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{2\cdot4x}{3x-1}}=?$$

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{2\cdot4x}{3x-1}$ would go to 8/3

Comment: @KaustabhaRay, So, we are done!

Comment: How is $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac2{3x-1}\right)^{3x-1}$ going to be simplified?

Comment: @KaustabhaRay, Have you noticed Use $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)^n=e$$

Answer (score 2):

You may transform the variable linearly ($3x-1=t$) to make a term disappear in the denominator and make the expression more familiar.

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{3x+1}{3x-1}\right)^{4x}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(\frac{t+2}t\right)^{4(t+1)/3}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(1+\frac2t\right)^{4t/3+4/3}.$$

Then with a rescaling, you remove another coefficient

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(1+\frac2t\right)^{4t/3}\left(1+\frac2t\right)^{4/3}=\lim_{u\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1u\right)^{8u/3}\cdot1=\left(\lim_{u\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1u\right)^u\right)^{8/3}.$$